# Invalid certificate chain error - Jenkins

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins

I can access my git repository using domain name on we browser with an certificate error.
But I need to use its IP address and sslverify=false to clone it using command line or git client.

Now I wanted to setup Jenkins for my iOS project but no matter what I use (domain or IP address), I am getting "Invalid certificate chain error" in Jenkins log.

I have also tried manually trusting the certificate from safari and also installed skip certificate check Jenkins plugin with no luck.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checkout on the below link, they have explained all the necessary steps to avoid any kind of every. Let's hope you are not missing any https://shinesolutions.com/2011/06/23/ci-with-jenkins-for-ios-apps-build-distribution-via-testflightapp-tutorial/

Comment: Was the link helpful, can you update if you are still facing issue?

Comment: @anshulGupta Great tutorial indeed, but doesn't seems to contain anything related to certificate chain error. I already have configured everything like mentioned in the link but not able to proceed further due to above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins might not be using the system Java
Each version of Java can have their own certificates stores. You most likely need to add the certificates to the stores.

Jenkins on windows has java installed in the Jenkins home directory. you need to find the cacerts file. and then use the keytool in the java directory to install the entire chain if it's a self signed certificate.

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -noprompt -storepass changeit -alias ROOT -file ROOT.pem
keytool -import -trustcacerts -noprompt -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -alias ISSUER -file ISSUER.pem
keytool -import -trustcacerts -noprompt -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -alias SERVER -file SERVER.pem
```

This should solve your issue with the certs.

Please check that you have added the certificate to the right Java by checking which Java install Jenkins is using.

Comment: Still facing same issue. I have used "/usr/libexec/java_home” to locate java home dir.
"cacerts" was located under "jre/lib/security." in java home.
Then I have used following command in security dir to import my certificate


sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -noprompt -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -alias <myalias> -file <pem file path exported from safari>

Comment: Did you install the whole certificate chain from the root ? Also is this a self signed certificate ? Also are you sure that Jenkins is opening in this Java install ? You should be able to check with a file in the install.

Comment: Safari exported pem file contains only 1 cer.
Yes, it is self signed cert.
Not sure, is there any way I can confirm it?

Comment: yes the export will only contain 1 file, but there should be a chain of certificates back to a root, I am not sure how to obtain them from safari but in chrome you can get the whole chain.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins doesn't support GIT system configuration and GIT Global configuration.
In my case, I added curl-ca-bundle.crt in GIT/bin directory.

I get it from Windows GIT.

git --version

git version 1.7.11.msysgit.0

and run below command to set https verification false.

git config --system http.sslVerify false

git config --global http.sslVerify false